# Boot Camp running Windows 10 returns error code 0xc000021a

Tags: windows-10, boot-camp, macos-mojave

My MacBook Pro (Retina, 15-inch, Mid 2014) running macOS Mojave version 10.14.6 failed to boot in Windows 10 via Boot Camp. I was prompted with Windows auto repair system saying it would search for errors. It returns the error code 0xc000021a and claims it wants to reboot. Upon restarting, it begins this whole cycle over again. This might be due to the fact that it can't boot windows up like it would on a normal desktop machine. Anytime I wish to run windows I must press the option key and select to run windows. I've tried typing things into a command prompt but it won't fix the issue. Some commands people have suggested want me to reboot, but doing so just sends me back to the auto repair cycle. I can't boot Windows 10 in safe mode because that also requires a restart. Any ideas or am I better off reinstalling windows? Thanks!